# How do I know when a precedence graph is representable by COBEGIN-COEND?

Tags: concurrency

I'm starting to study concurrent programming.

I know that there are precedence graphs that can't be represented only using COBEGIN-COEND construct (introduced by Dijkstra in 1968).

So...

Is there any algorithm to know when a precedence graph is representable by COBEGIN-COEND ??

Thank you very much,

Pablo.